# MRTK Unity взаимодействие с объектами

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вкратце: создаю небольшое приложение на Unity для гарнитуры Windows Mixed Reality с использованием Microsoft Mixed Reality Toolkit v2. 
Заметил одну особенность, которая мне мешает: при захвате объекта контроллером, компонент Rigidbody этого объекта становится кинематическим ( isKinematic = true ), что мне сильно мешает при взаимодействии с другими объектами во время операции перемещения.
После того, как отпускаю объект, он опять становится нормальным ( isKinematic = false )[image: Объект покоится]

[image: Объект поднят]

Вопрос: как убрать кинематику при захвате объекта контроллером?

Comment: Ну, видимо, код из этого плагина выставляет объекту такое значение. И, вероятно, это ему зачем-то нужно. Я бы почитал документацию на эту тему. Скорее всего, там же можно найти и решение не требующее менять исходный код плагина или пилить костыли

Comment: Оффтоп: а не подскажите, что за профайлер у вас внутри сцены?